How to use multiple animation blueprints given an array of AnimInstances?
My custom skeletal mesh component has a variable called AnimClassArray which takes an array of UAnimInstance / ABP Animation Blueprints:
UPROPERTY(...)
TArray<TSubclassOf<UAnimInstance>> AnimClassArray;


I'm trying to get all these Arrays of AnimationBlueprints to effect the skeletal mesh one after another
e.g. if I had ABP_StandardMovement, ABP_FootIK & ABP_AimWeapon inside the array I'd like the output of an ABP to pass into the input of the next one as such:

Unfortunately "Linked Anim Graph" Node doesn't seem to have the "Instance Class" variable exposable as a pin
I'm open to any C++ and/or Blueprint solution or even creating a custom node.
